Visa applications to the UK - are they processed in your home country or sent to and from the UK?
My Russian daughter in law is applying for a UK standard visitor visa to come on 2 week visit to the UK with her husband my (British) son and their daughter. When they applied for their daughter to get a British passport the documents were sent to the UK and the passport sent back from the UK - all good but takes time. I wondered if it is the same for visas for foreigners just visting the UK?

From this list of the decision-making centres for UK Visitor visa applications from Russia, all seem to be in the UK. However AFAIK, passports are not actually sent there, instead the local Embassy/VAC issues the visa vignette.

Ah so they make the decision in the UK but print the vignette in the home country eg Russia - thanks
